# Windows 8.1 installer: "Boot device failed"

Tags: boot, usb, windows-8.1, bootable-media

I have a notebook that came with Windows 8.1, but formatted the HDD and installed Linux to a 64GB partition after a failed Windows 10 upgrade. Now, I want to dualboot Windows 8.1 with Linux. I selected USB in the Boot Device Menu, but I get a error that reads:

`The selected boot device failed. Press ENTER to continue.`

It happens on both Legacy and UEFI mode.

I tried made the installer bootable by:

1. Using Disk Image Writer on Linux (did not show up in Boot Menu afterwards).
2. Creating a NTFS partition, copying all the files from the ISO into it, and adding a Bootable flag. (caused "Boot device failed).

I know the ISO works because it booted from it in a virtual machine.

How do I get the Windows 8.1 installer to boot?

Comment: What format is the USB stick, and what software/procedure did you use to make it bootable?

Comment: @ViRALiC I tried Disk Image Writer on Linux and manually making a bootable USB (more detail added in the question).

Comment: You can't make any usable Windows installation media from Linux nowadays, except when using MKUSB. If you have access to a Windows PC just do it there with the official tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, as stated by @user772515, was the boot tool I was using.

UNetbootin and Disk Image Writer in Linux wouldn't make a bootable USB, so I used [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) (for Windows) to create one.

It only booted in BIOS compatibility mode (I might have selected `NTFS` instead of `FAT32`), but the Windows 8.1 USB would finally boot and install.